# Trying to make a bash script that restarts all services within a certain directory

Tags: linux, bash

I have made this simple little script to try and restart all services within a directory:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    systemctl daemon-reload
    for service in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*
    do
        systemctl restart $service
    done;
```

When I try to run this I get the following error:

```
    Failed to restart etc-systemd-system-multi\x2duser.target.wants-openvswitch.service.mount: Unit etc-systemd-system-multi\x2duser.target.wants-openvswitch.service.mount failed to load: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the `basename` from the `$service` variable

```
systemctl restart "$(basename "$service")"
```

Or you can use `${service##*/}` which will remove up til and including the last slash:

```
systemctl restart "${service##*/}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively change working directory to avoid basename or parameter expansions:

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl daemon-reload
cd /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants

for service in *; do
  systemctl restart "$service"
done
```